# Visual Studio Code searching with regular expression flag modifiers?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

For example, how do you set the `i` flag to perform a case insensitive match? Is it even possible?

In code I would usually do something like `/needle/i`

The [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics) only makes a passing reference to the fact it uses the [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) regex engine. The docs there didn't help me either.

Answer (score 5):

In the find panels, selecting the "`Match Case`" option turns a case-insensitive search into a case-sensitive search.  So if the option is not selected, the search is case-insensitive.

[image: find panel: match case]

Comment: I suppose behind the scenes this sets the regex `i` flag. Was curious if there was a more general way of applying regex flags though. Looks like they've provided a slightly simplified regex interface. Probably with good reason.

Comment: One of the first links in ripgrep's README is a link to the [docs for its regex syntax](https://docs.rs/regex/1/regex/#syntax). Among them are examples for applying flags within a regex. e.g., `(?i)foo` will match `foo` case insensitively. (This is fairly standard syntax for regexes, and is supported by both Perl and Python.)

Comment: Unfortunately, that syntax does not work in vscode.  I do have the pcre option enabled.  (?I)anything errors.